# Removing question mark from query string

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

My goal: rewrite URL from **host.com/?abc** to **host.com/abc** and be able to request it via $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']. I found the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?$1 [L,QSA]
```

But for whatever reason, my $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] is empty, unless I put '?' in front of the query string. When I do print_r( $_SERVER ) or print_r( $_GET ), my query string is not present anywhere. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

UPDATE;
I'm using nginx as a 'front' proxy and redirect requests to apache using the following rule:

```
 server
 {
  listen   80;

  root /var/hosts/hostcom;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  server_name host.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {

          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8010;

   }

   location ~ /\.ht {
          deny all;
  }
 }
```

If I request the apache port directly, it works host.com:8010/?abc, but not through nginx, any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: it depends on routes, but `host.com/abc` should put "abc" in `$_GET`...

Comment: @Random that's the problem, do you know why it doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files):

> If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri
>   specified in the last parameter is made.

The `try_files` rewrites any request for a nonexistent file to just `index.php`, losing the path before it ever reaches Apache.

I believe your location blocks should look more like this, which should forward any request for a missing file to Apache without rewriting it:

```
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @apache;
  }

  location @apache {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8010;
   }
```